# Skip row in gridview asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview showing academy name and a dropdown list. The dropdown list have value of 0-13, 0 is the "Please select option". I want when the save button it skip those row where there is no selection in the dropdown therefore 0.

Here is my code for the gridview:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gdvAcadSelec" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        DataKeyNames="acad_Id"
        DataSourceID="srcAcademy"
          OnRowDataBound="gdvAcadSelec_RowDataBound"
        CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered"
        EnableViewState="False">
        <Columns>
             <asp:BoundField DataField="acad_Id" HeaderText="Id"  />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="acad_name" HeaderText="Academy"  />
 

             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Choice">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPref" OnTextChanged="ddlPref_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server">
                              
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:Button ID="btnsubmit" CssClass="btn btn-info" OnClick="btnsubmit_Click" runat="server" Text="Submit" />

    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="srcAcademy"
        TypeName="dataAccessLayer"
        SelectMethod="getAcademy"
        runat="server" />
```

The code behind for the binding of item for the column Choice:

```
      protected void gdvAcadSelec_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            //Find the DropDownList in the Row
            DropDownList ddlCountries = (e.Row.FindControl("ddlPref") as DropDownList);
            ddlCountries.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please select"));
            ddlCountries.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("1"));
            ddlCountries.Items.Insert(2, new ListItem("2"));
            ddlCountries.Items.Insert(3, new ListItem("3"));
            ddlCountries.Items.Insert(4, new ListItem("4"));
            ddlCountries.Items.Insert(5, new ListItem("5"));
            ddlCountries.Items.Insert(6, new ListItem("6"));
            ddlCountries.Items.Insert(7, new ListItem("7"));
            ddlCountries.Items.Insert(8, new ListItem("8"));
            ddlCountries.Items.Insert(9, new ListItem("9"));
            ddlCountries.Items.Insert(10, new ListItem("10"));
            ddlCountries.Items.Insert(11, new ListItem("11"));
            ddlCountries.Items.Insert(12, new ListItem("12"));
            ddlCountries.Items.Insert(13, new ListItem("13"));
        }
```

On click save button:

```
 protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        foreach (GridViewRow row in gdvAcadSelec.Rows)
        {
            DropDownList ddlorder = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlPref");

           
            string acadID = row.Cells[0].Text;

            string order = ddlorder.SelectedValue.ToString();

                SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand();
                scmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                scmd.CommandText = "Insert into tblAcademy_Selection (acad_Id,stud_Id,order_preference) values (@acad,@stud,@order)";
                scmd.Connection = con;
                scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@acad", acadID);
                scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stud", 60);
                scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@order", order);
                con.Open();
                scmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            
        }
}
```

The problem with this code is when it is saving to the database ,those dropdowns list who have value "please select" is also being save and this crash my website.
What can I do to skip those dropdown that do not have value selected?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have to know the value that you're trying to insert into the database before you insert it, so why not use an if {} statement to avoid trying to insert a value that causes an error?

Comment: I have try to put the insert statement into "if(order ==0)" it is not good. The row with the value 0  in the dropdown list must be loop for insert. How can I do that?

Comment: So the problem is you're trying to insert a string into an integer field?  Or is "Please Select" is too long for the character field?  If that's the case, and the index matches the value (except for 0 of course) can use ddlorder.SelectedIndex.ToString() instead.

Comment: I don't it to save the neither the 0 value nor the "Please select". I want to skip these field. Is that possible?

Comment: "I want to skip this field."  That's exactly what my first suggestion was, but you said you wanted to save the 0 as well.  Which is it?

Comment: Ahh my mistake, I want to save the rows that do not have the dropdown value 0. Can you post the first suggestion code and I test and mark it as solved if its ok?

Comment: As suggest in answer below - just put a if statement around the insert for checking if the value chosen is 0. This design will allow a user to select multiple of the same value. And if they ever wind up on that same page, and run it a again, they will be re-inserting a whole new set when existing order records exist. (but, maybe that is desired). But, with those inserts, then the user certainly can't go back and edit, or change those settings. (so if this setup is only one time, and you insert? - then ok. If you need ability to go back and edit, then you wind up inserting records again).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Edited per request from OP)
Simply use an if() statement to skip the values you don't want to insert.

```
string order = ddlorder.SelectedIndex.ToString();
if (order != "0") { // Some may argue that it should be !order.equals("0") but in C# it doesn't matter.
    SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand();
    scmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
.
.
}
```

And if you're a prudent (and paranoid) programmer, you won't trust anything sent from the browser, you'll check to make sure the variable `order` is the appropriate type and is within the range of values you expect as well.

Comment: Please change ddlorder.SelectedValue to ddlorder.SelectedIndex in your post so that I mark it as solved.It is ok with SelectedIndex.